# How does this check whether the form was submitted?

Tags: php

HTML:

```
<form name="myform" action="process.php" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="check_submit" value="1" />
    <!-- ........ -->
</form>
```

PHP:

```
if (array_key_exists('check_submit', $_POST)) {....}
```

Why can `array_key_exists('check_submit', $_POST)` check whether the form was submitted?

I've seen `isset($_POST['...'])` used before, but not this.

if i don't do this array_key_exists('check_submit', $_POST) decision., what may happen.

Comment: Is there some reason that it shouldn't?

Comment: Should be `isset($_POST['...'])`... no underscore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`check_submit` is a field in your form, so when you submit the form, that field is available in the `POST` data.

PHP places incoming `POST`-method form data into the `$_POST` superglobal array, and your code determines whether the `check_submit` field can be found in that array.

Indeed, it's quite similar to `isset($_POST['check_submit'])`, in that it checks whether such an element exists in `$_POST`. It's just taking a slightly different approach.

---

If you did not submit the form, then of course there is no form data.

Comment: @runeveryday: If you submit the form, could you submit the form? Huh?

Comment: i am sorry, i mean if i don't fill all the input text box. then i submit the form, the data which typed part could insert into the database?

Comment: @runeveryday: I'm having trouble understanding you. When you submit a form, any data that you entered into it is submitted to the webserver, and any PHP script that you may have running at the destination URI. That PHP script may do whatever it likes with the data it receives.

Comment: if i don't do this array_key_exists('check_submit', $_POST) decision., what may happen.?

Comment: @runeveryday: I have no idea. That would depend on how the PHP script is structured. The script may believe that a form submission has occurred when it has not; in a typical basic design, you may always get empty inserts into your database and never see an actual GUI. But this is just guesswork. Examine the code and see for yourself!

Answer (score 3):

To check wether your page was called as a result of a form submit (via POST) you should use something like this:

`if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')`

You shouldn't use hidden form elements just to have a value to check wether a form was submitted. If you use the request method you catch it more cleanly and don't have any trouble if the form ids/names/values are altered.

Answer (score 0):

Don't you mean something like:

```
 if(!empty($_POST) && isset($_POST['check_submit']) && $_POST['check_submit'] == '1'){
   // do something
 }
```

Comment: The last two conditions can be condensed, and the first is pointless.

Comment: $_POST appears to exist always, even in the CLI interpreter.

Comment: True...my bad...edited my answer a bit so it makes more sense. I was just pointing out some options to the poster.

Answer (score 0):

Do `var_dump($_POST)`, you will see the $_POST associative array, which will have check_submit key, and value = 1